# how do I call salesforce APEX From rest api

Tags: rest, salesforce

I find tons of articles explaining how to call rest apis from APEX - but I'm accessing salesforce from an integration system using the Salesforce REST API, and want to it the other way around.

ie -

I've found functionality (record merging) - that is not available from the rest API, but IS available from apex.  Is there any way to run an apex statement or script from the rest API?

NOTE: I'm aware that the functionality also available from the SOAP api, but we really don't want to go near that for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

you want to REST API endpoints in APEX, so that you can call this endpoint from anywhere, Right? if so then you need to check [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm) article.

After reading above article, you are able to create GET, POST, DELETE endpoint in your Salesforce Org and you can use this endpoints.

Comment: I'm building a tool that can work with any salesforce instance - so don't really have any ability to change anything inside the salesforce instance - I am looking for a way to merge two account objects from the rest api, or alternatively run an arbitrary line of apex - just like I can run a soql query - without changing anything in salesforce